# Is there a Hamcrest "for each" Matcher that asserts all elements of a Collection or Iterable match a single specific Matcher?

Tags: java, hamcrest

Given a `Collection` or `Iterable` of items, is there any `Matcher` (or combination of matchers) that will assert every item matches a single `Matcher`?

For example, given this item type:

```
public interface Person {
    public String getGender();
}
```

I'd like to write an assertion that all items in a collection of `Person`s have a specific `gender` value. I'm thinking something like this:

```
Iterable<Person> people = ...;
assertThat(people, each(hasProperty("gender", "Male")));
```

Is there any way to do this without writing the `each` matcher myself?

Comment: Probably you can use the everyItem Matcher: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/matchers/JUnitMatchers.html

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use the [`Every`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/Every.html) matcher.

```
import org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue;
import org.hamcrest.core.Every;
import org.hamcrest.core.Is;
import org.junit.Assert;

Assert.assertThat(people, (Every.everyItem(HasPropertyWithValue.hasProperty("gender", Is.is("male")))));
```

Hamcrest also provides [`Matchers#everyItem`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#everyItem%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) as a shortcut to that `Matcher`.

---

Full example

```
@org.junit.Test
public void method() throws Exception {
    Iterable<Person> people = Arrays.asList(new Person(), new Person());
    Assert.assertThat(people, (Every.everyItem(HasPropertyWithValue.hasProperty("gender", Is.is("male")))));
}

public static class Person {
    String gender = "male";

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that generics is causing problems. I'm getting a compilation problem because `assertThat()` expects argument types `T, Matcher<?super T>` but it's getting `Iterable<Person>, Matcher<Iterable<Object>>`

Comment: @E-Riz I've updated with a full example. If yours is different, please edit your question to include it.

Comment: You example still has the generics-related compilation problem, but only when compiled against JDK 7; with JDK 8 it compiles fine. I wasn't aware that the generics spec changed between 7 and 8 but apparently they realized the compiler was being stupid and fixed it.

Comment: To get it to compile for Java 7, I had to declare the hasProperty Matcher like this: `HasPropertyWithValue.<Person>hasProperty("gender", is("Male"))` which pretty much destroys the readability improvements that Hamcrest is supposed to provide :-(

Comment: And beyond that, woohaaa, reflection and by-string access. I find that super-ugly. I would rather manually iterate the collection and assertThat() on Person::getGender() than ...

Answer (score -2):

More readable than the approved answer and no separate assertions in a loop:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

assertThat(people).allMatch((person) -> {
  return person.gender.equals("male");
});
```

Comment: but that is not Hamcrest