# ArrayList<Boolean> Assertion Java without hamcrest

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, assertions, rest-assured

This test gives me all statuses as a Boolean value of either True or False from API:

```
List<Boolean> allStatus = event.getResponse().getBody().jsonPath().getList("enabled");
```

There is no specific idea of how many status there will be, and there is no fixed size; it could be size 20 or 1.

To check this assertion, I was running a for loop and checking each value:

```
assertNotNull(allStatus);
for (Boolean status : allStatus) {
    assertEquals("FAILED Disable event status ", false, status);
}
```

I want to know what is there a better way to handle such a scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by better? Are you looking for shorter? It can't get faster.

Comment: Do you want to stop after the first failure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Hamcrest "for each" Matcher that asserts all elements of a Collection or Iterable match a single specific Matcher?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860135/is-there-a-hamcrest-for-each-matcher-that-asserts-all-elements-of-a-collection)

Comment: @JonahGraham That's a different library.

Comment: @4castle yes, but it doesa answer the question of a better way, ie use a better library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Java Streams's [`allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
assertNotNull(allStatus);
assertTrue(allStatus.stream().allMatch(b -> !b));
```

Comment: Actually, you might want to revert to `b -> !b` because the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Boolean.java#Boolean.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for `equals` does unboxing also. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You could use `streams` introduced by Java 8:

```
List<Boolean> allStatus = new ArrayList<>();
allStatus.stream().forEach((status) -> { assert status; });
```

This is basically doing the same as the code you provided, but with newer technology. You can't make it any faster because you **do** have to check every single entry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do a single assertion?

```
boolean tmp = true;
for (Boolean status : allStatus) tmp = tmp&&status;
assert tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can aslo use below assertion :

```
List<Boolean> allStatus = event.getResponse().getBody().jsonPath().getList("enabled");
assertNotNull(allStatus);
    assertEquals("FAILED Disable event status ", false, allStatus.contains(Boolean.valueOf(true)));
```

Comment: I think this will check only once that status is there or not. In allStatus, It will be all status of different event